# Android Studio 0.8.2 : How to add local Project Library?

Tags: android, android-studio, library-project

i am a android app developer and converting myself from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Now i get a difficulty to add library project into another project.

What i can do in **Eclipse** is very clear:
1.Set project B as library Project (right click->properties->android->is Library)
2.Add this library into Project A (right click->Properties->android->add...->choose Project B->OK

But how can i execute such behavior in AS?
I read article 
[Create a standalone library with Android Studio](http://geekgarage.dad3zero.net/create-a-standalone-library-with-android-studio/)

and Create Project A as Library in AS.

Now i create Project B in AS with module BApp,
how can i add Library Project A into B/BApp?

---

The reason i would not like to copy files of Project A to Project B is, I would also use Library Project A in my many other Project. I dont think it is a good idea that make a hard copy to each Project while i will always update Library A in local.

Appreciation for the Help!

Comment: Is your Project B in a filepath outside your Project A?

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to Project Structure and add the library as a new module. To do this click on the + icon and select Import Existing Project, once the module is imported go to the Dependencies tab, click on the + icon and select Module Dependency and click on your library.

Comment: I did this but There is no Project A in depedencies List. The Library Project A is a standalone Project in AS, not a module in project B. The reason is i could reuse A for many other Project.

Comment: still you should be able to add Project A as a module of B, this will not prevent you from adding it to other projects as well